# ¿Por qué le agregan el @ antes de llamar una funcion PHP?

Tags: php

Buenas solo quiero saber eso, he notado que hay gente que pone por ejemplo: @fopen() o @fwrite(), etc... No encuentro porque hacen eso asi que he venido a preguntar.

Comment: Es para ignorar los posibles errores generados, en realidad la considero una mala práctica, pero hay veces que cuando el tiempo apremia... http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es un *operador de control de errores* y evita que los errores dados en una función se muestren en el `html`.

Este operador `@` se aplica cuando se recibe el valor de algo, por ejemplo:

- variables
- llamadas a funciones
- includes
- constantes

No puede anteponerse a definiciones de función o clase:

- estructuras condicionales (if, else, switch,...)
- ciclos(foreach, for, while,...).

.

```
// la función file intenta abrir un archivo
$archivo = @file('archivo_inexistente') or
    die ("Archivo no se encontró: el error fue '$php_errormsg'");

// no le asigna nada en caso de no existir
$value = @$_GET['valor'];

// finaliza la ejecución en caso de no existir
(@include("archivo.php"))
   OR die("No encontró archivo.php!");
```

Dejo el [link de la documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) al respecto.